# Something between "satisfactory" and "good"

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for an adjective meaning something between "satisfactory" and "good".

For example, let's say we can rate something (restaurant, homework, etc.) and give it 1 to 5 stars, but we can also rate is as 3.5 stars. Which adjective can be used to describe 3.5 stars, i.e. better than satisfactory/average but not good enough to be just good?

Comment: I'd say it was **not half bad**.

Comment: You could say it was **decent**.

Comment: You might consider **Exceeded Expectations** here.  It has a positive connotation relative to your expectations, but doesn't veer too far from Satisfactory or Good.  (I've seen forms use "Exceeded Expectations" as 4 of 5, as well.)

Comment: How about "above average"?

Answer (score 2):

Other than "not bad" or "pretty good", there are a number of synonyms that mean somewhat less than "good", but something more than "OK":

> favorable, positive, satisfying, nice, pleasing, agreeable, commendable, gratifying, decent, fitting

The actual degree of "goodness" can vary with context and intonation.

> She thought the meal was *rather nice*, as the soup was *delightful*, and the entree *sufficiently gratifying*; however some of the other courses were *merely agreeable*.

Comment: Note that some rankings (mostly on either extreme of the spectrum) are entirely subjective. I've been in meetings where two developers vehemently disagreed whether "amazing" was better than "wonderful" or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can try **decent** here.

This is defined as: *fairly good, or conforming to the recognized standard of propriety, good taste or modesty*

In context:

 - "So what do you think about the lobster bisque here?"

 - "Hmm, not too shabby, it's actually **decent**."

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is that things get a little muddled with your use of the word _pretty_. I'd have trouble discerning the difference between your the review of the bisque ("Hmm, not too shabby, it's actually pretty *decent*")  and one that said, "Hmm, not too shabby, it's actually pretty *good*." It's tricky to pinpoint or quantify the strength of expressions like _pretty good, quite nice,_ and _halfway decent_.

Comment: Good point, perhaps the use of *pretty* is unnecessary here. Edited to reflect this change, thank you!